# Determining if a character is within the field of view in XNA

Tags: xna, collision-detection

I'm trying to creating a field of view for the camera I'm making for a game. It rotates around a circle for 180 degrees while the head moves accordingly. I'm going to bound the field of view within an isosceles triangle using the method described on [this website](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordtriangleareabox.html).

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how I'm going to detect if the field of view has intersected with the character as seen in [this link](http://www.robotfootgames.com/xna-tutorials/5-xna-platformer-starter-kit-field-of-view-for-enemies).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

[EDIT]

sorry I meant an asset in game representing a camera much like the enemy in the second link, not an actual camera class in XNA(really sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Linear Algebra for Game Developers](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-2/)

See the section titled Do Product. It has a tutorial for the math to determine whether an object is in the field of view of another object. Should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for that, this seems to be exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [BoundingFrustum.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.xna.framework.boundingfrustum.contains%28v=XNAGameStudio.10%29.aspx) function.  You give it the view and projection and it builds the frustum.  If you're going 2d, then you can add bounding boxes to a custom sprite class - [example is here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/6089.aspx).

Edit: [Check here for two different techniques](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html) for determining if a point is inside a triangle.

I think the bounding frustum could still work, but might be a bit more work.  You can use the BoundingFrustum for things other than cameras.  Each NPC would have to have a local view and projection to get their frustum and you can use that to check against a Vector3 (just set Z = 0 for Vector2).  If you wanted to draw the frustum for debugging, you can get the points of the box and project them back to 2D just by setting the Z to 0.